# How to transform encoded document characters coming in xml into text?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

i have a service which is returning some details along with a PDF document . The pdf document is coming encoded characters as shown below . I am sending this entire XML in JSON using write function . But when i trying without those encoded PDF Sections its working fine . But when i add encoded section the transform is failing . How i can handle it ? I think it may be anything to do with encoding .
[image]

In java i was able to make a PDF document from the document section like below

```
String pdfData = documentNode.getTextContent();
File file = new File("C:/Test");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(Base64.decodeBase64(pdfData.getBytes()));
fos.flush();
```

Without the CDATA section this is what i am expecting . I could not add the CDATA section in the output

```
<DRIVEResponse>
<Loan LoanNumber="12345678" DRIVEScore="0" TimeZone="EST" >
</Loan>
</DRIVEResponse>

%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
write(payload, 'application/xml')
```

Output

```
 "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n<DRIVEResponse>\n  <Loan 
  LoanNumber=\"12345678\" DRIVEScore=\"0\" 
  TimeZone=\"EST\"/>\n</DRIVEResponse>"
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do a `write(payload, 'applicaton/xml')` with a payload that is already XML, and with output set to `application/json`. Try just changing it to `payload` under the `---`

Comment: "junk characters" is meaningless and not useful to provide help. You have to know what the data mean, or at least clarify from where it come. For example if it is the PDF encoded in some format like base64.

Comment: Also you should provide the input and transformations as text, even if the screenshot is useful for showing the error.

Comment: Updated the question with the information i hava

Comment: @ Michael Jones , i need to send this XML as a text to another service .

Comment: It is not clear how did you try to add the CDATA section, it is not mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the XML CDATA section seems to be malformed. Note how the CDATA beginning delimiter last bracket is in a separate line:

```
       <![CDATA
       [...
```

In the [XML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-cdata-sect), it is a single token `'<![CDATA['`.

The DataWeave playground, writing it separated causes that error. Just use the CDATA delimiter together and that should fix the issue, unless there is another problem in another section of the document:

```
       <![CDATA[
       ...
```

UPDATE:
After reading the comments I see that there are other possible problems. My understanding is that you are reading and converting a PDF file to base64 in Java, then tried to add it as CDATA in the XML output. I see some issues in there.

First, if the PDF is binary using a Java string could cause encoding issues and corrupt the file. You should use a byte array (`byte[]`) instead.
Second, it is not clear how are you adding the CDATA section. Based on the error I'm assuming just concatenating the string.

DataWeave provides features for both encoding binary data to base64 and to generate CDATA sections, in a simpler and safer way.

Example:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import toBase64 from dw::core::Binaries

var binaryPdfData="FILE READ FROM FILESYSTEM" as Binary // this is usually a binary payload read from the File connector. As an example I am converting a string to binary
var base64PdfData=toBase64(binaryPdfData)
var outputTemplate=    { 
        DRIVEResponse: {
            Loan @(Number: "12345678", DRIVEScore:"0", TimeZone:"EST"): {
                Document @(fileType: "pdf"): base64PdfData as CData

            
            }
        }
    }
---
write(outputTemplate, "application/xml")
```

Comment: Hi , i updated the question with the information i have . I was able to make a PDF doc from the encoded section in the XML . So i think the response is fine .

Comment: I provided a more complete answer